# Google geocode suggest result is appearing behind the modal

Tags: geocoding, google-geocoding-api

I have a problem with google geocode suggest. I have a modal which show a form to complete an address. I have implemented geocode to make easier the address filling, but the suggest is appearing behind the modal, like this:

[image: Google geocode suggest issue]

Some code over here:

JS which implements geocode:

```
GoogleGeocode = (function () {
var _api = {};
var _googleApiRetrievedOk = false;
var _autocompleteEvent;
var _addressInputId, _zipCodeInputId, _countryInputId, _countryComboboxId;
var _componentToRetrieve = {
    street_number: 'short_name',
    route: 'long_name',
    locality: 'long_name',
    administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
    country: 'long_name',
    postal_code: 'short_name'
};

function loadGoogleApis() {
    // Importar fuentes
    $('head').append($('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />').attr('href', 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500'));

    // Importar api Places
    $('head').append($('<script type="text/javascript" />').attr('src', 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true&libraries=places&callback=GoogleGeocode.GoogleGeocodeInit'));
}

function googleGeocodeInit() {
    _googleApiRetrievedOk = true;
}

$(document).ready(loadGoogleApis);

return _api;
})();
```

View which supports modal:

```
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-1">
            <h2>@T("StudentData")</h2>
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-CTA" data-dismiss="modal">X</button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-header">
        @Html.Action("PrepareStudentDataModel", "Topic")
    </div>
</div>
```

Part of view which calls google geocode:

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Address1, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = @T("wke.checkout.StudentAddress.geocodeaddress") })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Address1)
        <span class="col-md-6 col-xs-6 field-validation-valid" id="StudentAddress_address1MessageValidation" style="visibility: hidden;">
            @T("wke.checkout.StudentAddress.messagevalidation")
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: add code snippet to show efforts you have put..! unless it is hard to find a bug.

Comment: Added! If you need some part of code, tell me!